# Is it possible to automatically move PS/AI toolbars?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, tools

I work using a 15in MacBook Pro and a 27" Thunderbolt display. I use the two of them as separate screens.

My problem is that it's hard to move my entire program (ie: Photoshop/Illustrator) all at once. I have to move the window, then tool bars, etc..

Is there a shortcut to this that pulls all of the menus over? Also, I'd like to not be forced into fixed toolbars.

Comment: You can save a usi preset for 2 cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the application frame (**Window → Application Frame**). With the application frame active your whole workspace is treated as one window that you can easily move/resize etc.

From [Illustrator Help / Workspace basics](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/workspace-basics.html):

> The Application frame groups all the workspace elements in a single, integrated window that lets you treat the application as a single unit. When you move or resize the Application frame or any of its elements, all the elements within it respond to each other so none overlap.

Also if you are using OS X you can simply drag your entire space from one screen to another without having to move any of your windows (which is what I do). If you aren't using [spaces](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21872?locale=en_US), you should. They are incredibly useful.

Comment: I thought they didn't want the Application Frame because of the statement, "Without Fixed windows" - guess I was wrong!

Comment: @Ryan you can just enable the application frame, move the window then disable the application frame. My second point about moving your whole desktop space is far easier though.

Comment: I should probably clarify that I chose to do this with with Spaces tool, as that seems to be easier.